Hashtable Synchronization Issue
I am trying to test the Synchronization in Java Hashtable.
Below is the code. It should output 1000 always. But it is not the expected behaviour.
Can someone please explain why it is behaving this way?
    Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<>();
    map.put("key", 0);
    Runnable task = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);
        }
    };

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(task);
        threads[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Hashtable value: " + map.get("key"));

output : 1000 but it is not giving 1000 always.

"please explain why it is behaving this way" -- you kind of answered it yourself: "Synchronization Issue" (short example: Thread1 reads 5 and before writing back, Thread2 reads 5 too {since not synchronized}; now Thread1 increments and writes 6, finally Thread2 also increments {it also read 5} and writes 6 itself - now we are one short)

BTW, just for some ideas, from the documentation of HashMap (not synchronized as opposed to the Hashtable): "If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally." - changing a value is not such a change...

Hashtable is synchronized meaning that two threads can not update it at the same time, however there are no guarantees about the values used by those threads. In your case each thread may overwrite each others last update.

by the way, being at "different index" is not relevant - problem can even happen if loops are at the same index

Thanks for pointing that out. Updated to remove the index reference.

The Hashtable is "synchronized", which means that only one thread can use any method without interfering from other threads, but only as long that method is called by the thread. This ensures that the object itself doesn't "get broken" where the internal "bucket" structure is modified at the same time by multiple threads.
However, your line
map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);

is not (such) an atomic operation. In fact you have two separated calls map.put() and map.get(). By the time one thread A is reading the current value via map.get("key") a different thread B could have read the same value or already set a new value for the same key before the original thread A have save its increment. Check the timing below:



Thread A
Thread B




map.get("key") = 5




map.get("key") = 5



5+1 = 6


5+1 = 6




map.put("key", 6) -> "key" is at 6


map.put("key", 6) -> "key" is already at 6




Now you "lost" one increment because thread A hasn't seen the increment already done by thread B.

Let's revisit this line:
map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);

We have three operations here, let's split them in their order:
int value = map.get("key")
value = value + 1
map.put("key", value)

Hashtable methods are synchronized internally. Meaning that, when a thread calls them and executing the code inside, others are waiting:
Thread A: map.get("key")
Thread B: map.get("key") // blocks here until Thread A will get the value
Thread A: // goes further

Thread A usually is fast enough to perform 3 operations while Thread B is taking its' access, but 'the life happens':
int value = map.get("key")
// <---- Thread B is ALREADY here
value = value + 1
// <---- Thread A is STILL here
map.put("key", value)

Both will act on the same value from the Hashtable

Wrapping the code with additional synchronization is a one of many cures:
synchronized (this) {
    map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);
}


Just to sum up what's mostly already said in comments:
The Hashtable makes sure that no other thread intervenes while one thread is inside a get() or put(). It does not help for code outside.
But in your code line
map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);

there is a moment when the map.get() has finished, and before the map.put() takes place.
There, a thread switch can happen. The code has left the synchronization of the map.get() and not yet entered the synchronization of the map.put(), so some other thread gets the chance to use the map (get a value and put the incremented value).
The Hashtable being thread-safe only means that the complex internal structures don't get mixed up if multiple threads do map.get() and map.put() calls.
For your example, you need to do your own synchronization that also covers the time span between the map.get() and the map.put(), e.g. by
synchronized (map) {
    map.put("key", map.get("key")+1);
}

If your threads don't compete for the same ky, but always use different keys, you'll get the expected results with a Hashtable. The difference to a HashMap (declared not to be thread-safe) is that a HashMap can get completely messed up even in the case of non-conflicting keys.
